# redirect ethernet packets through sk_buff to localhost

Tags: linux, networking, kernel

I am writing a Linux  kernel module which redirects a packet to the localhost webserver ,which was originally forwarded through this machine using bridge  . It also redirects to reply to the client . The client is oblivious of the redirection . So there are 2 parts
  1. all forwarded packets through bridge  to some webserver outside  are redirected to local webserver .

2. The output of the localhost webserver is channelled to the original client

I am able to do the second part through nf_hook NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT

```
unsigned int snoop_hook_reply( unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff *skb,
    const struct net_device *in, const struct net_device *out,
    int(*okfn)( struct sk_buff * ) )
{
    int offset, len;
    struct ethhdr *ethh;
    struct iphdr *iph;
    struct tcphdr *tcph;
    bool flag = false;
    struct net_device *eth1_dev , *lo_dev;

    if (!skb) return NF_ACCEPT;
    iph = ip_hdr(skb);
    if (!iph) return NF_ACCEPT;
    skb_set_transport_header(skb, iph->ihl * 4);
    tcph = tcp_hdr(skb);
    /* skip lo packets */
    if (iph->saddr == iph->daddr) return NF_ACCEPT;
    if (tcph->dest == htons(80))
            flag=true;
    if(flag != true)
            return NF_ACCEPT;

    // correct the IP checksum
    iph->check = 0;
    ip_send_check (iph);

    //correct the TCP checksum
    offset = skb_transport_offset(skb);
    len = skb->len - offset;
    tcph->check = 0;
    if(skb->len > 60){
    tcph->check  = csum_tcpudp_magic((iph->saddr), (iph->daddr), len, IPPROTO_TCP, csum_partial((unsigned char *)tcph,len,0));
    }
    else{
    tcph->check  = ~csum_tcpudp_magic((iph->saddr), (iph->daddr), len, IPPROTO_TCP, 0);
    }

    //send to dev
    eth1_dev = dev_get_by_name(&init_net,"eth1");
    lo_dev = dev_get_by_name(&init_net,"lo");
    skb->dev = eth1_dev;
    ethh = (struct ethhdr *) skb_push(skb, ETH_HLEN);
    skb_reset_mac_header(skb);
    skb->protocol = ethh->h_proto = htons(ETH_P_IP);
    memcpy (ethh->h_source,eth1_dev->dev_addr , ETH_ALEN);
    memcpy (ethh->h_dest, d_mac, ETH_ALEN); // d_mac is mac of the gateway
    dev_queue_xmit(skb);

    return NF_STOLEN;
}
```

the above code works perfectly for me . One issue is that later on I will mangle the packet so need to create a new sk_buff, probably .

I am not able to do the 1st part through NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING, I am not able to push the packet/sk_buff to the webserver process through the TCP/IP stack. I tried using dev_queue_xmit() function with skb->dev as both eth1 and lo . I am seeing the packets hitting on the lo or eth1 through tcpdump . But the packets are not reaching the localhost webserver. Can anyone help me regarding this or point to some similar answered question . I believe instead of dev_queue_xmit() I need to call some receiving function . Also when packets arrive in NF_INET_PREROUTING, I the ethernet headers are already there so I am not forming it . 
I have already accomplished the above tasks in variety of ways , first using raw sockets , then using nf_queue , now I want to see the performance through this method.
Thanks

Comment: sounds like you are doing transparent proxy, can't you use some existing iptable module to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive the packet locally, you cannot call dev_queue_xmit() on eth1 as it will be sent out. You probably need to call netif_rx() after pointing the skb->dev to eth1/lo.

One more point is if the dest-ip is not your local host ip, then you need to avoid routing again otherwise, there will be no use of your interception.
To achieve this, either you need to modify packet's dest ip to eth1/lo IP or
fool the IP layer by using skb_dst_set() to set "rth->dst.input= ip_local_deliver" for packet to be accepted as local packet.